# Angular 8 window.open change name of the window

Tags: typescript, angular8, window.open

I have a service that returns a blob of a PDF. I need to open this PDF in a new window, without downloading it, giving it the name I want. The problem is that I can't set the name to this window and the file.
Right now I do:

```
          const fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(pdf);
          window.open(fileUrl);
```

and the window that opens is:

[image]

Is there a way to change that generated url and name of the window?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
const fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(pdf);
let w = window.open(fileUrl);

w.addEventListener('load', function () {
    w.document.title = "foo1";
})
```

I tried it in my code and it's look working.

Comment: Hi, I've tried this code but what happens is that while the window is loading it has the title "this has changed", but then once loaded I got the generated title

Comment: Instead of setTimeout I am doing it on load. Can you try once again ?

Comment: Hi, I've tried with the new solution but nothing has changed

Comment: @Usr Can you provide some code to reproduce (Stackblitz or somthing) so I can look ?